# Qt multithreading - can t execute thread multiple times

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am trying to run a thread continuously. What happens in my case is that every time the thread is done executing I can't start it a second time. I went through the class functions to see whether there would be something like restart() or whatever but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Could somebody tell me what I may be missing?

```
  webcamClass::webcamClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
  {
      recognizePerson=false;

      //setup recognition thread
      recognitionThread = new QThread(this);
      recognitionClObj = new recognitionClass();

      connect( recognitionThread, SIGNAL(started()), recognitionClObj,       SLOT(recognizePerson()) );
      recognitionClObj->moveToThread(recognitionThread);

  }

  void webcamClass:: getVideoFrame()
  {
      qDebug()<<"this is the webcam thread";
      static cv::VideoCapture cap(CV_CAP_ANY);
      cv::Mat imgFrame;

      if( !cap.isOpened() )
      {
          qDebug()<< "Could not initialize capturing...\n";
      }

      while(1)
      {
          cap >> imgFrame;
          cv::cvtColor(imgFrame, imgFrame, CV_BGR2RGB);
          QImage img;
          img = QImage((uchar*)imgFrame.data, imgFrame.cols,       imgFrame.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888);
          QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
          emit gottenVideoFrame(pixmap);
          if(recognizePerson==true)
          {
              recognitionThread->start();

              qDebug()<<"started recognition thread";
          }
          cv::waitKey(100);
      }
  }

   int recognitionClass::recognizePerson()
   {
        qDebug()<<"recognizing person";
    }
```

generated output:

```
            this is the webcam thread
            started recognition thread
            recognizing person
            started recognition thread
            started recognition thread
            started recognition thread
            started recognition thread
            started recognition thread
            started recognition thread
            started recognition thread
            started recognition thread
```

As you can see the sentence "recognizing person" only gets printed 1 while I expected it to be printed multiple times just like "started recognition thread"

Ideally I d like the thread to wait unitill it receives new data. It should do that 20 times and then return new data.

Answer (score 0):

connect( recognitionThread, SIGNAL(started()), recognitionClObj,       SLOT(recognizePerson()),Qt::DirectConnection);

you may try add Qt::DirectConnection in your connection

Answer (score 0):

Your recognitionThread is already started, so every further call to start does nothing, nor generating any new started signal. If you want your recognitionClass to do new work you have to connect another signal to the slot recognizePerson.
So define a signal in your webcamClass

```
signal:
    void doRecognize();
```

add a second connect to your webcamClass signal to the recognitionClass

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(doRecognize()), recognitionClObj, SLOT(recognizePerson()));
```

and instead of recognitionThread->start() issue

```
emit doRecognize();
```